# Hibernate forming the wrong query it seems

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc

My requirement is to extract all the distinct rows(name column alone) where name is not null
This is my hibernate code.

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("name"));
ProjectionList list = Projections.projectionList();
list.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("name")),"name");
criteria.setProjection(list);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(A.class));
result = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

The SQL formed is below:

```
select distinct this_.name as y0_ 
from dbo.A this_ 
where y0_ is not null
```

The error is `ERROR - Invalid column name 'y0_'`
I dont understand why hibernate is forming the wrong query like this.
Any help appreciated.

Code for class A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int skillId;
    private String name;

    public A() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SKILL_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getSkillId() {
        return this.skillId;
    }

    public void setSkillId(int skillId) {
        this.skillId = skillId;
    }

    }

    @Column(name = "name", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you add criteria.setResultTransformer() ? And you probably do not need to add alias to the projection.

Comment: I have tried it already.The problem is, in the resultant object all fields are null.Without specifying the alias name for "name", hibernate is not mapping the "name" attribute correctly to A object.Without setResultTransformer, I am getting class cast exception

Comment: I have resolved issue by appending "this." to all the restrictions column names. In this case Restrictions.isNotNull("name")); should be Restrictions.isNotNull("this.name"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out following:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
ProjectionList projectionList2 = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList2.add(Projections.distinct(projectionList.add(Projections.property("distinctColumn"), "distinctColumn")));
projectionList2.add(Projections.property("col1"), "col1");
projectionList2.add(Projections.property("col2"), "col2");
criteria.setProjection(projectionList2);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class)); 
List list = criteria.list();
```

In you case, "distinctColumn" will be "name".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("name"));
ProjectionList list = Projections.projectionList();
list.add(Projections.property("name"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(list));
```

Comment: I have tried it already.The problem is, in the resultant object all fields are null.Without specifying the alias name for "name", hibernate is not mapping the "name" attribute correctly to A object.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem, Creating an alias solved the issue, try:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a")
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("a.name"));
ProjectionList list = Projections.projectionList();
list.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("a.name")),"name");
criteria.setProjection(list);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(A.class));
result = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```